# CodeIgniter show div after receiving request from Controller

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, codeigniter

I want to show a specific `div` class in my view ... but first I have to check whether sepecific data is successfully entered into the data base through ajax and if not then other dive error class will appear above for some time and then hide.

Here is my view JavaScript code.
Here I am popping a dialog box if event occur suceesfully which I want to turn into a div class that if something true is happened then "div success message" else div failure message.  I think  I have to  pass a specific parameter from controller to view but I dont know how to do it.

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
          $('#btn').click(function() { 

var item_name = $('#item_name').val();
var cat_id = $('#cat_id').val();

if (!item_name || item_name == 'Name') {
    alert('Please enter Category Name');
    return false;
}

var form_data = {
        item_name: $('#item_name').val(),
        cat_id:    $('#cat_id').val(),
    ajax: '1'       

};

$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('itemsController/additems'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(msg) {
        //$('#message').html(msg);

        alert("items added successfully");
          $('#item_name').val("");



    }
});

return false;
     });


    </script>
```

this is my controller

```
function additems(){

    //getting parameters from view 
    $data = array(
            'item_name' => $this->input->post('item_name'),
            'cat_id' => $this->input->post('cat_id')

    );


    $is_ajax = $this->input->post('ajax'); //or use this line
    //$this->input->is_ajax_request();

    $this->load->model('itemsModel'); 
    $query = $this->itemsModel->addItemstoDB($data);


          if ($query && $is_ajax){             //if the user c validated
        //data variable is created becx we want to put username in session


         $page['main_content'] = 'itemsView';

         $this->load->view('dashboardTemplate/template',$page);


    }
    else
     {
        echo "not added";
    }
    }




     }
```

model

```
        class ItemsModel extends CI_Model {


public function addItemstoDB($data){

    $successfull = $this->db->insert('item',$data);


    if ($successfull){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

this is not how to deal with ajax in your controller at all:

first I''m going to assume that your model is returning `true` if inserted and `false` if not then:

your controller:

```
function additems(){
//your processing goes here.
    $result = array();
    $this->load->model('itemsModel'); 
    $query = $this->itemsModel->addItemstoDB($data);
    //var_dump($query); the results will be desplayed either on your page or you can see it using firebug in firefox
    if ($query ){  //&& any other condition
        $result['res'] = 1;//process successful - replace 1 with any message
    }
    else
     {
        $result['res'] = 0;//process failed - replace 0 with any message
     }
       echo json_encode($result);//at the end of the function.
    }
```

then your ajax part:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('itemsController/additems'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {
        if(msg.res == 1)
        {
          $("your div").removeClass("error").addClass("ok");
        }
        else{
          $("your div").removeClass("ok").addClass("error");               
          }


    }
});
```

Comment: thanks it help me a lot and it works 99% ... 1% is where i am getting problem is when i implement your code ..i just replace          $("your div").removeClass("error").addClass("ok");                                            $("your div").removeClass("ok").addClass("error");                                       these two lines with alert boxes true and false ... and then when i run the script it outputting  the false in a dialog box ..but the data is successfully adding into  database..

Comment: okay, fast typo error. I updated it. added array declaration at the first :). is there any other things?

Comment: i replace these lines for testing purpose

Comment: I added the $result array declaration at the top of the function. have you updated your code with it?

Comment: yup i did that... according to your logic as the query is successfully running it should print true ... but its printing false but data is adding into database successfully ... may b the view is not getting the value '1' ..dont know wats wrong in this

Comment: and also I updated the string output to be integer. that might mislead  jquery also try to update it in your code. just review my edits

Comment: are you sure that $query is returning true?

Comment: nope nothing happens ..and data is storing into database as usual

Comment: Updated. just delete the comment and use it. then you can know what is the result of returning $query. or you can check the model you have to see what is your addItemstoDB function returning. it should return true or false. in boolean format. if not adjust it. or you can update your question and add your model function addItemstoDB to check it out.

Comment: @user1961812 - you have to delete the comment out of it so you can use it.

Comment: this is what i am getting a response  {"res":"1"} in firebug

Comment: have you copied my last update. I switched the string response to be an integer. from "1" to 1. have you updated that?? in the controller and ajax.

Comment: yeah... i updated it but same thing.  now i am getting this {"res":1}

Comment: thank you helped me a lot ... i done it ..actually i have to delete one equal sign in ajax     if(msg.res = 1)... now it is working fine ... thanks you a lot.

Comment: there must be something wrong!!OK, debug your code as: delete var_dump. check that your ajax is the same as I posted exactly.

Comment: do you have an hotmail/yahoo/facebook/skype any id .. if you can give me then i'll b very thankful to you..

Comment: no, no, this is wrong. msg.res=1 is not a condition. you have to check via == not =

Comment: ok i changed it ..but didnt work .. you were right ..i was wrong there